# equivalent of ruby ...? in haskell

Tags: haskell, naming

In ruby `?` is allowed at the end of identifier which allows things like

if do_something?
      do_something

which allow to differientiate function returing a bool from function doing something.

In Haskell, obviously the type signature tells you the difference between those two function, but is there a name convention or naming pattern to name bool or options ?

In my case, I want to generate (or not) some labels depending of the value of an options (passed as argument).

the obvious code would be

```
generate options = do
     when (generateLabels? options) generateLabels
```

but as `generateLabels?` is not valid name, how can I call it ?

Comment: I don't see how this question can be answered without being opinionated.  I am not aware of a convention, but I might name it as `labelsAreNeeded :: Options -> Bool`.  Then it would read like the english sentence "when labels are needed given options, generate labels".

Comment: No, not really. Other than the obvious convention of giving such function names that sound like they represent something truthy.

Comment: @bheklilr: It is a bit opinionated indeed but the communauty could have a general conventionfor it. However, I like your answer, even thugh it doesn't work as a general pattern (as the `?`)

Answer (score 6):

If you glance at the functions [that return Bool](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+Bool), you'll notice that the convention is to use a predicate that when used in code reads like a sentence. For example:

```
isDenormalized :: RealFloat a => a -> Bool
isSigned :: Bits a => a -> Bool
isAlphaNum :: Char -> Bool
```

In your function I'd suggest that you rename `generateLables?` to something like `needsLabels` as @bheklilr pointed out in order to make your code more readable.

Comment: I would like to point out that there are exceptions to this rule, namely `even`, `odd`, `null`, and a handful of others, but in most libraries outside of `base`, the convention of using some verb in the function name is quite common.

Comment: I usually use the `is...` patttern but couldn't find anything corresponding to my case. `needsLabels` is exactly what I need.